# Reset Redis database after each test in laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, phpunit, laravel-testing

In my laravel application, I use Redis to store some cache (e.g. the list of items to show on the front page). I always access Redis through the Facade: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis`.

I created a different Redis database for testing (`1` instead of `0`), but I also need to reset it after each test, so that the test never gets data from a previous test.

Is there an efficient way to create this behaviour?

I tried to implement it using the `@before` annotation:

```
/**
 * @before
 */
public function prepareForTesting() {
    Redis::flushdb();
}
```

But I get the error: `Cannot use 'FLUSHDB' over clusters of connections.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you unable to use the `Cache` facade ? If it's only for caching this is the recommended approach and in tests the default cache driver is an array so always gets reset between tests

Comment: I managed to refactor my code and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the built in artisan `cache:clear` command?

Like this:

```php
/**
 * @before
 */
public function prepareForTesting() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
}
```